# Lambda Expression: CS to VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda

I am dumb founded at this statement....maybe its just too many hours/days of doing C# to VB.Net conversion but i am drawing a blank on this conversion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
List<string> sColors = new List<string>(this.CustomPaletteValues.Split(','));
try {
   List<Color> colors = sColors.ConvertAll<Color>(s => (Color)(new ColorConverter().ConvertFromString(s)));
```

What i have so far:

```
Dim colors As List(Of Color) = sColors.ConvertAll(Of Color)(....)
```

As you can see its the content of the lambda that i am hitting a brick wall with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon the line breaks, but I believe this is what you want.

```
Dim colors As List(Of Color) = sColors.ConvertAll(Of Color)(
    Function(s) DirectCast((New ColorConverter).ConvertFromString(s), Color)
)
```

Comment: thank you....found this kewl tool [link](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/) Developer Fusion Toolbox

Answer (score 1):

```
sColors.ConvertAll(Of Color)(Function(s) DirectCast(((New ColorConverter).ConvertFromString(s)), Color));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in a far more shorter way with implicit typing:

```
    Dim colors = sColors.ConvertAll(Of Color)(
        Function(s) (New ColorConverter).ConvertFromString(s))
```